# Button Pressed by Owner of Spreadsheet or not?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to ensure that certain buttons (images) when pressed either run a script if the owner of the spreadsheet clicks it, or displays a message if any other User clicks the button.

I thought I could use getActiveUser and getEffectiveUser to identify if the current user was the person that created the spreadsheet.  When I assign the following script to a button however, I get the message stating I am 'NOT the owner'.

```
function UItest() {
  if (Session.getActiveUser() == Session.getEffectiveUser()) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("I am the owner")
  } 
  else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("I am NOT the owner")
  }
}
```

On displaying getActiveUser and getEffectiveUser, both appear to give the same email address.

What would be the proper way of identifying if the active user of the spreadsheet was author/owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are comparing objects, not strings. call getEmail() before doing the comparison.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser

Comment: Thanks for that - totally missed that I had not added .getEmail()  I had read that page but because my check was returning the email address, I thought it was something else.  Doh!